# Loop div contents from input and get the values from the textboxes inside of the div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to loop a div not more than the inputted number. The user must input how many boxes and then the box details (length,width,etc..) will loop depends on the value of the number of boxes. I also need to get those data and save it on the database (I'm using mvc, btw). Here is my code in html:

```
 <div>
     <input type="text" class="inputText" name="num_boxes" id="num_boxes" onkeypress="return numberOnly(event)" style="height:5%; width:100% !important;" required />
     <span class="floating-label" style="left: 0 !important;">No. of Boxes</span>
     <input type="text" hidden id="txtnum_boxes" name="txtnum_boxes" />
</div>

<div id="PackageDetails">
    <!--THIS IS FOR THE THIRD ROW IN THE LEFT CORNER-->
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group row" style="margin-top: 1%;">

        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="padding-left:0; padding-right: 5px;">
            <div>
                <input type="number" class="inputText" name="length" id="length" style="height:5%; width:100% !important;" required />
                <span class="floating-label" style="left: 0 !important;">Length</span>
                <input type="text" hidden id="txtlength" name="txtlength" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="padding-left:0; padding-right: 5px;">
        <div>
            <input type="number" class="inputText" name="length" id="width" style="height:5%; width:100% !important;" required />
            <span class="floating-label" style="left: 0 !important;">Width</span>
            <input type="text" hidden id="txtwidth" name="txtwidth" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="padding-left:0; padding-right: 5px;">
            <div>
                <input type="number" class="inputText" name="height" id="height" style="height:5%; width:100% !important;" required />
                <span class="floating-label" style="left: 0 !important;">Height</span>
                <input type="text" hidden id="txtheight" name="txtheight" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--THIS IS FOR THE THIRD ROW IN THE LEFT CORNER-->
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group row" style="margin-top: 1%;">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="padding-left:0; padding-right: 5px;">
            <div>
                <input type="number" class="inputText" name="volumetric_weight" id="volumetric_weight" style="height:5%; width:100% !important;" required />
                <span class="floating-label" style="left: 0 !important;">Volumetric Weight</span>
                <input type="text" hidden id="txtvolumetric_weight" name="txtvolumetric_weight" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="padding-left:0; padding-right: 5px;">
        <div>
            <input type="number" class="inputText" name="total_weight" id="total_weight" style="height:5%; width:100% !important;" required />
            <span class="floating-label" style="left: 0 !important;">Total Weight</span>
            <input type="text" hidden id="txttotal_weight" name="txttotal_weight" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried javascript for looping but I dont know if I'm doing it right as I just saw it also on the internet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var packageDetails = document.getElementById("PackageDetails"),
    form = document.getElementsByTagName("num_boxes")[0],
    numOfBoxes = num_boxes.value();
    i;
    for (i = 0; i < numOfBoxes; i++) {
    var clone = packageDetails.cloneNode(true);
    form.appendChild(clone);
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're using `getElementByTagName()` but you aren't looking for a tag. `num_boxes` isn't a tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName. Also you want `value` and not `value()` and also after you declare `numBoxes` you use a semicolon, so `i` will not be defined.

Comment: Please add the rest of your code - we can't see any `<form>` elements, or anything with `num_boxes`.

Comment: The `num_boxes` is the name of the input not the form

Comment: Oh sorryy... but how can I get the value from num_boxes?

Comment: If you want to get an input value try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/9h45nmsv/1/

Answer (score 0):

`<num_boxes>` tag is not defined here. So might be meant to use form name or form id. So, correct your code. Eg: `document.getElementById(‘num_values’)`